# ruby on rails, file upload and database

Tags: database, ruby-on-rails-3, file-upload

maybe it's a question already ask but i did not find a answer.

Hello all.

I'm new ruby on rails.

I'm using Ruby 1.9.3 and rails 3.0.5, i want to create a page to upload file (video) on the shared folder of the server and when the file is upload i want to save the name of the file on my database (SQLITE3).

After i want to use the  of HTML5 to list all the video i have on an other page.

The structure look like : Home -> click on button upload file -> upload page file -> return home to see the video list.

If possible i want to make it hand made, no gems.

For now i have try something like mix : http://french.railstutorial.org/chapters/user-microposts#top and http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby-on-rails/rails-file-uploading.htm. But did not get anything so far the work.

Thank you for the help.

p.s. : sorry if my english is not really good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a reason people use gems. They provide flexibility and simplicity into application. Gems is blessing and not using gems when you can is a total waste of time. As for this application, please consider Carrierwave gem. One was specifically designed for file uploads. [Here](http://railscasts.com/episodes/253-carrierwave-file-uploads) is a railscast video on how to use it. I'm sure you'll find it pretty simple and awesome to use.

Comment: Thanks i gonna look at this

Comment: thanks but i really don't understand how to use this, i can't install rmagick, that's why i did not wanna use gem

Comment: Then don't use Rmagic, what's the problem. Rmagic used for some manipulations with images.

Comment: Oki thanks i found how to install et use it with image. i has not read what was Rmagic before.

Now i have to make for video.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use paperclip gem to upload image.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).